# Codeigniter updated SQL problems

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

After updating from codeigniter 3.1.0 to 3.1.9 a module for the current website is having some problems, looking at the SQL it outputs it would be because of the order_by section but I can see from the SQL error that a few to many ` are being added however have no idea how to fix this output..

The Code block having problems:

```
interface IssueFlags
{
 const FLAG_NONE       = 0x000;
 const FLAG_PINNED     = 0x001;        // issue is pinned, will always stick to the top of other issues
 const FLAG_PRIVATE    = 0x002;        // issue is limited only to staff and are not visible for others
 const FLAG_LOCKED     = 0x004;        // issue is locked and is not editable by anyone, only staff are allowed to edit
 const FLAG_CLOSED     = 0x008;        // issue is not opened to comments anymore, only staff are allowed to comment
}

public function get($id = false, $limit = false)
{
    if($id = array_filter((array)$id, 'is_numeric'))
        $this->db->where_in('bugtracker_issues.id', $id);

    if(is_numeric($limit) && !empty($limit))
        $this->db->limit($limit);
    elseif(is_array($limit) && count($limit) == 2)
        $this->db->limit($limit[0], $limit[1]);

    // Limit columns to get proper data and prevent duplicate columns name overwrite eachother
    $this->db->select('bugtracker_issues.*, account_data.nickname');

    // Also join a few columns of account data, so we won't need to query for each user too
    $this->db->join('account_data', 'bugtracker_issues.author = account_data.id', 'left');

    // This allow us to use functions when bulding our query
    $this->db->protect_identifiers = false;

    // Sort issues by update then created timestamp, at the end their id and descending, pinned ones always comes first
    $this->db->order_by('`flags` & ' . self::FLAG_PINNED . ' DESC, IFNULL(`update`, `create`) DESC, `id` DESC');
    $this->db->protect_identifiers = true; // turn it off, as its default state is disabled

    $query = $this->db->from('bugtracker_issues')->get();
    if(!$query || !is_object($query))
        return false;

    if(!$query->num_rows())
        return array();

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Error that is happening:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 DESC, IFNULL(`update`, `create`) DESC, `id` DESC LIMIT 20' at line 4

SELECT `bugtracker_issues`.*, `account_data`.`nickname` FROM `bugtracker_issues` LEFT JOIN `account_data` ON `bugtracker_issues`.`author` = `account_data`.`id` ORDER BY `flags`` &` 1 DESC, IFNULL(`update`, `create`) DESC, `id` DESC LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ORDER BY` clause is not valid.

```
ORDER BY `flags`` &` 1 DESC, IFNULL(`update`, `create`) DESC, `id` DESC LIMIT 20
```

This does not make sense in SQL.

You need to fix that part of the PHP code to generate a proper `ORDER BY` clause :

```
$this->db->order_by('`flags` & ' . self::FLAG_PINNED . ' DESC, IFNULL(`update`, `create`) DESC, `id` DESC');
```

Should be written as :

```
$this->db->order_by('`flags` DESC, IFNULL(`update`, `create`) DESC, `id` DESC');
```

Comment: Not valid how? from what I can tell by testing the SQL output to make it work, the & "& ' . self::FLAG_PINNED . ' DESC" part outputs " `flags`` &` 1 DESC," removing the ` from around the & causes the SQL to work fine.

Comment: But "`flags`` &` 1 DESC" means nothing in SQL, hence the SQL error

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the backticks... It's normal that Codeigniter escapes everything with backticks for your own protection, which is why you see them in the error message. I concur with @GMB ... The `order_by` statement is incorrect